# The code always goes to the else loop and sends the error message. Is the code wrong?

Tags: php

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $query = $_POST['message'];
    $email_from = $name.'<'.$email.'>';

    $to="someone@gmail.com";
    $subject="Enquiry!";
    $headers .= "From: ".$email_from."\r\n";
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n".PHP_EOL;
    $message="mail sent";


    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
    {
        header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Successful Submission! Thankyou for contacting us.");
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Error To send Email !");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: SO is not a free debug service, please do your own debugging.

Comment: My weapon of choice is http://swiftmailer.org/ , certainly not the built-in mail() function.

Comment: @whitebeard no, because this code isn't working as expected it would be **off topic** there.

Comment: Okay, I will remove my down vote then if the site will let me...

Comment: Do i have to use the phpmail() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $query = $_POST['message'];
    $email_from = $name."<'.$email.'>"; //Check Properly Here

    $to="someone@gmail.com";
    $subject="Enquiry!";
    $headers .= "From: ".$email_from."\r\n";
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n".PHP_EOL;
    $message="mail sent";
    $SendMail=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); //Check Here Too

    if($SendMail)
    {
        header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Successful Submission! Thankyou for contacting us.");
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Error To send Email !");
    }
}
?>
```